# Hardware Integration with PHP Application

Tags: php, hardware

I am aware that PHP is a server side language so it can't access hardwares like barcode, rfid and others. Currently we are developing a School Management system (WebApp). Our client need barcode and biometric features for library and attendance. We like to know if there is any technique to do this?

Please help me with this.

Thank you.

Comment: Maybe [oDesk](http://www.odesk.com) or [Freelancer](http://www.freelancer.com) would be a better place for this?

Comment: You need a `Com object` or `java applet` , `Silverlight` or any plugin that exposes hardware interface. Definitely not what you can do in pure `PHP`

Answer (score 0):

This might help you..maybe instead of trying to get the hardware to work, switch it up and use mobile phones to scan barcodes, that way you don't even need extra hardware as every librarian will have a mobile phone.

The bio metric part might be a little tricky, but Im sure theres some sort of face recognition library for android that you could use, then this mobile system, integrates with your online web app and youre good to go with a full working system.

http://phpmyweb.net/2012/07/18/integrating-zxing-in-your-android-app-as-standalone-scanner/

Comment: How is this related to the question ?

Comment: Im suggesting that they can find ways around using a hardware scanner, by using a phone as a scanner....and creating a web/mobile app for it.......not that hard.

Answer (score 0):

You have to store this class from http://www.phpro.org/classes/Generate-Barcodes-With-PHP.html and call that from where you want to create the barcode like this

```
$bar= new barcode();
$barnumber  = $caseid;
$bar->_encode   = 'CODE128';
$bar->_color        = '#000000';
$bar->_bgcolor  = '#FFFFFF';
$bar->_height   = 30;
$bar->_font = 'font/arial.ttf';
$bar->_scale    = 2;
$bar->_format   = 'gif';
try{
    $bar->genBarCode ($barnumber, 'gif', 'barcodes/'. $caseid.’gif');
}
catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage()."\n";
    echo $e->getLine()."\n";
}
```